# How to stretch last grid item across full width of screen, when it goes to new row?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
gap: 1rem;
```

When there is not enough space to fit all three containers to fit, one of my containers jump down. Which is fine.

Then the grid has 2 columns and 2 rows. I want the last element to occupy full width of sceen. So, to occupy 2 grid rows instead of one. I can do this manually with media-query, but isn't there a better way to do it?

Comment: No, that's what flexbox is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if grid is your best option in this scenario.
You might want to use a flex container, setting flex-grow: 1 and min-width on the items.

Example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  min-width: 30rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

And then using negative margin on the container, plus margin on the items to use as the gap.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it. Wanted to use grid as I wanted the containers to have gap between and box shadow. The grid looked really good regarding gaps. Not sure yet how I will do same gaps between flexes, but will try to figure  it out :)

Comment: As I suggested, try adding: 
.container { margin-left: -1rem; margin-right: -1rem }, then
.item { padding-left: 1rem, padding-right: 1rem }, it will have a similar effect as the gap, do something similar vertically. That's how packages like Bootstrap does it.

Comment: Thanks. I will also try this solution. In meanwhile I did .container {padding: x amount} and .flex-items {margin: x amount}. As container padding collapses with margin on flex. So for now works like a charm. Wondering if the solution you have written is better or not.